# Fail to import Jackson Jersey and Jersey Client in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, dependencies

I am in trouble in using Jersey dependencies with Android Studio.
Here is my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile files('libs/jersey-client-2.8.jar')
compile files('libs/jersey-media-json-jackson-2.8.jar')
}
```

I add the following import to my Activity :

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
```

And I keep having the same ERROR :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.julie.myapplication, PID: 30599
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig
```

It seems that the import fail, could someone please help me ?
Thanks a lot, 
Julie

Answer (score 0):

From Jersey version 2.16, it should be possible to use Jersey Client on Android. The support is still not perfect. [refer this](https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/jersey_2_x_client_on) this info might be helpful who searches about Support of Jersey Client in android..